# Touch and find the sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to find the sprite(polygon) among multiple sprite when i touch the sprite.

I am trying the following code but it is not working.

CCTouchBegan event:

```
CCPoint point = this->convertTouchToNodeSpace(ptouch);

CCRect bomb11Rect = CCRectMake(bomb->getPosition().x ,
                               bomb->getPosition().y ,
                               bomb->getContentSize().width,
                               bomb->getContentSize().height);

CCRect posRect = CCRectMake(point.x ,
                            point.y ,
                            1,
                            1);

if (bomb11Rect.intersectsRect(posRect))
{
    CCLog("Touch the sprite");
}
else
{
    CCLog("Not Touch the sprite");
}
```

Any one give me idea to fix the above issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the bomb rect using:

```
CCRect bomb11Rect = bomb.boundingBox
```

Then check it touch is inside this rect using:

```
CGRectContainsPoint(bomb11Rect, point)
```